# pick values based on name from ps -ef output

Tags: shell, awk

I need to collect two columns based on the values from "ps -ef |grep"  command output . In our organization users are trying starting pgbouncer with different command and options. my requirement is to to pick
pgbouncer binary and its configuration file

here is the example :

```
[root@sl273pgb01 pavan]# ps -ef |grep pgbo
pgbounc+   1655      1  0 Jan11 ?        00:15:05 /usr/bin/pgbouncer -d -q /etc/pgbouncer1/pgbouncer.ini
pgbounc+   1678      1  0 Jan07 ?        00:15:05 /usr/bin/pgbouncer  /etc/pgbouncer2/pgbouncer.ini -d -q
pgbounc+   1699      1  0 Jan09 ?        00:15:05 /usr/bin/pgbouncer -d   /etc/pgbouncer3/pgbouncer.ini -R
```

OP's efforts:

```
ps -ef |grep pgbo |awk '{print $ 7 " " $8}'
```

from the above output,  in need to get output as  below

```
/usr/bin/pgbouncer  /etc/pgbouncer1/pgbouncer.ini
/usr/bin/pgbouncer  /etc/pgbouncer2/pgbouncer.ini 
/usr/bin/pgbouncer  /etc/pgbouncer3/pgbouncer.ini
```

please help me how can I get desired output.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user has not tried anything yet.

Comment: Hello Daedron, I was able to pick  "/usr/bin/pgbouncer" with ps -ef |grep pgbo |awk  '{print $ 7  " " $8}' . but *.ini position is not consistence.  If I have some logic and I can write code for it

Comment: If you're not required to use `awk`, using some other tools may make this simpler since it's probably not clear the form of the config file path (e.g., is it always an absolute path), or its position in the command line.  Something like this command may help `ps -ef | tr -s [[:space:]] ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 8- | sed -e 's/-. *//g'`  (I'll leave it to you to look up the particular commands in that sequence)

Comment: @Durga, good that you shown your efforts please add them in your question. Also could you please confirm if parts like `/usr/bin/pgbouncer` and `/etc/pgbouncer.......` are always same kind of pattern? Kindly confirm once?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following, this is not this will work irrespective of position of `.ini` in your ps command.

```
ps -ef | 
awk '
  match($0,/\/usr\/bin\/pgbouncer/){
    val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    match($0,/\/etc\/pgbouncer[0-9]+\/pgbouncer\.ini/)
    print val,substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  }
'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
ps -ef |                                ##Running ps -ef command and sending its output to awk command as an input here.
awk '                                   ##Starting awk program from here.
  match($0,/\/usr\/bin\/pgbouncer/){    ##Using match function which matches /usr/in/pgbouncer anywhere in current line.
    val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)       ##Creating val which has sub string of matched above regex.
    match($0,/\/etc\/pgbouncer[0-9]+\/pgbouncer\.ini/)  ##Using match function to match /etc/pgbouncer digits/pgbouncer.ini in current line.
    print val,substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) ##Printing val value and sub string of matched regex here.
  }
'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use awk if you use the output format option of ps (-o) and so:

```
ps -eo pid,cmd | grep "pgbo"
```

Comment: this Piece of code is working as well.  Just Modified code as below ``` ps -eo cmd |grep pgbo|grep -i ".ini" |sed 's/-[a-zA-Z]//g'``` . Thank you so much for much simple idea

Answer (score 0):

Tested in GNU `awk`

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html

> "If regexp contains parentheses, the integer-indexed elements of array are set to contain the portion of string matching the corresponding parenthesized subexpression"(`match()` function).

```
awk '{match($0,/(\/usr\/bin\/pgbouncer).*(\/etc\/pgbouncer[0-9]+\/pgbouncer\.ini)/, arr); print arr[1], arr[2]}' file
/usr/bin/pgbouncer /etc/pgbouncer1/pgbouncer.ini
/usr/bin/pgbouncer /etc/pgbouncer2/pgbouncer.ini
/usr/bin/pgbouncer /etc/pgbouncer3/pgbouncer.ini
```